# how to manage dataset with big number of columns?

Tags: scala, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib, pca, one-hot-encoding

I m working with data values that come from sensors. This data is extremely big. If I want to work with dataframe I have to work with a number great then 250000 of columns. These data are 10% numerical and 90% categorical. I want to transform data into numerical using OneHotencoder and then extract future using PCA to apply machine learning algorithm: kmeans. The main problem here is that the dimension is so big.
any suggestion please